# The errors do not show on VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm setting up my VS Code for C++. I use version 1.31.1 x64 on windows 10, install C/C++ extension version 0.21.0. Below are my settings:

`c_cpp_properties.json`

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "MinGW",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/include/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "LOCAL"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "compilerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

`task.json`

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "C++ compile and run",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++ \"${file}\" -O2 -static -std=c++14 -DLOCAL -o \"${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe\" && \"${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe\"",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "presentation": {
                "clear": true,
                "echo": false,
                "panel": "shared"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My simple test program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "hello world"
}
```

I ran the code by above task. The code was missing a semicolon, but the errors were just shown in terminal tab, while nothing appears in problems tab, also on text editor. Did i miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the setting to turn on the error squiggles:

`Preferences` -> `Setting` -> search for `Intellisense` -> choose `Enable` in `C_Cpp: Error Squiggles`.

You should check both User settings and Workspace settings.

Comment: there is nothing to do with task.json